# Realm store constant number of items on disk

Tags: android, realm

I'm using Realm database in my Android application and receiving a lot of data from the server like `CustomModel(id,name,date)` and I need to store only last N `CustomModels`.

Is there possibility to do that with Realm?

Comment: Last N items of what?

Comment: Last N items of my model.

Comment: You can save them all with a timestamp field, then `findAll` & `sort` & delete the first total - N items.

Comment: Yes actually I have timestamp, but as for me it looks weird, first to get items and then to delete